Create menu bar app macos using html (iframe)
It is my first time using a tool to create a menu bar app, and I would like to create one for a calculator. (Indeed, I did not find a good menu bar app for this, and I would only need to add this <iframe.) https://www.numworks.com/simulator/embed/how-to/ I am using this, so I only need to create a menu bar app that opens an HTML page. I tried to use this tool, https://github.com/max-mapper/menubar/, but I did not find a way to make it function. I get an zsh: command not found: yarn error.
Could you help me make to create a simple "hello world" (found in /examples) and create a simple menu bar app that would display some html? It would really make my day ☺️ thank you ! If you need some detailled informations, dont be afraid to ask me !

I am no JavaScript dev, but I know enough that you have to install node.js (using Homebrew that would be brew install node) and then yarn is installed with npm install -g yarn.  If you are gonna write anything based on HTML/JavaScript then you need to get to grips with that stuff first.
